# Changing the Auto Email Within Google Scripts Workflow app

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi all I am trying to modify the follow google scripts workflow (from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eduG0XZ9mDs&feature=plcp). I am trying to change the content of the auto generated emails. I tried changing the text within the code (ie from "Buy it!" to "This request was not approved". But no matter what I do the emails get sent with the original text. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var email = e.values[1];
  var Item = e.values[2];
  var cost = e.values[3];  
  var url = '<ENTER YOUR PUBLISHED URL>';  
  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'&reply='+email; 
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'&reply='+email;

  var html = "<body>"+
            "<h2>Please review</h2><br />"+
            Item +": " + cost+ "<br />"+ 
            "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
            "<a href="+ reject +">Reject</a><br />"+
         "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail("jjones@beaconcloudsolutions.com", "Approval Request", 
                "What no html?", {htmlBody: html});  
}

function doGet(e){ 
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Buy it!' : 'Not this time, Keep saving';   
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Purchase Request", 
                "Your manager said: "+ answer);     
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>An email was sent to '+ e.parameter.reply + ' saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
  return app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should log your code. So you can know what's the value of: e.parameter.approval, answer, etc.

But from what I observed, try to change your html var, so it will be like:

```
var html = "<body>"+
        "<h2>Please review</h2><br />"+
        Item +": " + cost+ "<br />"+ 
        "<a href='"+ approve +"'>Approve</a><br />"+
        "<a href='"+ reject +"'>Reject</a><br />"+
     "</body>";
```

I hope it will solve the problem.